# amazon s3 partitioning of files best practices

Tags: filesystems, amazon-s3

Hopefully a simple question - apologies if it's already been answered but nothing came up in search.

On S3 is it better to organizes images into smaller subdirectories, or just keep them all in one directory? In a typical filesystem one would namespace the images in directories to improve performance. A flat structure with thousands of images in one directory doesn't normally perform well. Is this the case on Amazon S3?

I can put all user images into a users folder, all post images into a posts folder, etc. OR I can put user images into folders like `users/{userId}` to avoid having thousands of images in one users folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update 2018-07

It is no longer required to account for performance when devising a partitioning scheme for your use case, see my InfoQ summary [Amazon S3 Increases Request Rate Performance and Drops Randomized Prefix Requirement](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/10/amazon-s3-performance-increase) for details:

> Amazon Web Services (AWS) recently [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/) significantly increased S3 request rate performance and the ability to parallelize requests to scale to the desired throughput. Notably this performance increase also "removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes" and enables the use of "logical or sequential naming patterns in S3 object naming without any performance implications".

#### Update 2013-09

The information in the referenced link, <s>while still largely
accurate</s>, has been supplanted by a newer document, [S3 Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html).

---

### Initial answer

This is a problem with Amazon S3 as well, albeit only for significant storage requirements, see [Amazon S3 Performance Tips & Tricks](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html) for a detailed answer including strategies for partitioning your object space.

Comment: I just want to add that the tips from the first link are obsolete now, and you might want to add that to your answer:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/
"This S3 request rate performance increase removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes to achieve faster performance. That means you can now use logical or sequential naming patterns in S3 object naming without any performance implications. "

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @CodesInTheDark - by chance I have even covered this significant and highly welcome improvement for InfoQ and have now updated the answer with a pointer to my resp. news post ;)

Comment: Any official document saying about "removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes"?

Comment: Yeah but what about 503 slow down errors? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-503-cross-region/

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are obsolete now
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/
"This S3 request rate performance increase removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes to achieve faster performance. That means you can now use logical or sequential naming patterns in S3 object naming without any performance implications. "

Comment: But I'm still facing 503 slow down errors https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-503-cross-region/: "this typically indicates that the requests exceed request rates per prefix.".. but what is a "prefix" and how do I control it?

Answer (score 1):

Its worth thinking of a scheme to chunk it up onto files... if for no other reason than just having a way to filter your files if you want to manually look around.

But dont spend too much time if you are certain as to all the ways you will need to commonly access your files... You can always migrate to a new scheme later.

*YEARS LATER*

I organize all buckets like this by default:

`bucket:/type/YYYY/MM/DD/human_useful_filename_UNIQ_STUFF.ext`

Where:

- bucket = the bucket name
- type = Type of artifact as defined by my app
- YYYY/MM/DD - what you think
- human_useful_filename_UNIQ_STUFF.ext -   I put something at least slightly debuggable as the 1st part of the filename, and then something to ensure it's unique in the suffix, followed by the regular extension.     That way, if you do find yourself lurking in S3's UI or console, you can at least try to ascertain what's going in (more useful in dev & test context, at least).

If you have lots of objects (on average > 1000 per day), then even splitting on HH is worth it too.

Comment: Well the filenames themselves will be prefixed with the user's ID so it's easy to find a particular users files with either method. More at issue here is wether normal filesystem concerns affect S3 (reduced performance with tens of thousands of files in the same folder).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering now, hoping that it might be helpful still,

In AWS key names determine which partition the object(file) is stored in - you could add **a hax prefix** to file name for better performance.

**GET-Intensive Workloads :** Use CloudFront

**Mixed Workloads (GET, PUT & DELETE) :** Use hax prefix to S3 object key names to prevent multiple objects being stored on the same partition.